# Assigning a unique ِmaster page to page layout In publishing portal in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

hope you are in a great health .

I have A SharePoint portal , the master page for this portal contains a lot of side navigation , I faced the below Case :

I have a page called service.aspx, And I want to hide the navigation for this page only, this page is based on page layout .

I tried to create A copy of the master page with no navigation and to assign this master page for the page layout but I couldn't because the site master page overrides the page one

Question related to this one , is there any way to hide master page elements using Script having this script in a page layout ???

or ,do you  have a solution for such problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a placeholder to your master page so you can disable some styles for the side navigation. This [article](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/06/18/single-master-page-and-layout-design-techniques/) has some really good information about what you will need to do to accomplish this.

In the master page, add a content placeholder inside the body tag’s class attribute and remove any runat=”server” attributes that the tag might have, as they are usually unnecessary with SharePoint and will cause an error.

```
 <body scroll="yes" class="<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID='PlaceHolderAdditionalBodyClass' runat='server' />">
```

Now in your page layout apply content to the placeholder, say in your frontpage.aspx you would write

```
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalBodyClass" runat="server">frontpage</asp:Content>
```

Your page that uses frontpage.aspx as it’s page layout now has the class frontpage on it’s body and you can reference that on your default stylesheet to make any exceptions for the default style declarations.

Assume you have a frontpage sans quick launch and a default layout which has a quick launch, you would do something like this to stretch the frontpage:

```
 #leftNavigationContainer {
          float: left;
          width: 200px;
  }

 #pageLayoutContainer {
          float: left;
          margin-left: 200px;
 }

.frontpage #leftNavigationContainer { display: none; }
.frontpage #pageLayoutContainer { margin-left: 0; }
```